# migrate failure (django 1.8)

Tags: django, database, terminal, migrate

I'm trying in vain to migrate my database to the server.  here is the traceback that I get from the terminal.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   File "/home/guimatsi/lib/python2.7/registration/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 150, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()   File "/home/guimatsi/webapps/nnmland/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.6-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Since I'm new in django and it's my first project, Every hint would be appreciated. ths in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using a version of Django registration that does not support Django 1.8. You could try installing [Django registration redux](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead.